# How to handle entries that could need the same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Site
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :site
end
```

And the post has the following columns:

```
id
site_id
url
title
body
```

This is going to store wordpress posts, and I want to use the `post_id` of wordpress post, and because of that I could have two sites that would have the post `1` for example. So I need a way to have duplicated post ids, but pointing to different entries.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of this use case, it's a bad practice to make your ActiveRecord `id` rely on another data source.

For your case, ignore the conventional `id` and store the WordPress post ID in a new column, let's call it `wp_id`, which is not unique across the table.

Then, you can create the following index to make queries faster and assure the uniqueness of post ID per site:

```
add_index :posts, [:site_id, :wp_id], unique: true
```

This way, you get what's called a *composite key*, means every combination of both `site_id` and `wp_id` is unique across the `posts` table.

Comment: Great! That's what I needed.

Comment: Just to make sure. Where this should be added?